# `-Wa,-divide` option in Clang or LLVM

Tags: assembly, clang, llvm, xv6

I am porting [xv6](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public) from GCC to Clang, and met the following error message:

```
clang -m32 -gdwarf-2 -Wa,-divide   -c -o swtch.o swtch.S
clang-3.8: error: unsupported argument '-divide' to option 'Wa,'
```

Note that `-Wa` is used to pass arguments to the assembler, and I couldn't figure out what is the `-divide` option.

As a fix, currently I switched off the integrated assembler by passing the `no-integrated-as` option to Clang.  But I want to use Clang's integrated assember.  Is it safe to ignore this option?  Or is there an alternative way to give that option to Clang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gas manual [documentation for `--divide`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dOptions.html#index-g_t_0040samp_007b_002d_002ddivide_007d-option_002c-i386-1011) says:

> On SVR4-derived platforms, the character `/` is treated as a comment character, which means that it cannot be used in expressions. The `--divide` option turns `/` into a normal character. This does not disable `/` at the beginning of a line starting a comment, or affect using `#' for starting a comment.

On my Linux desktop, `--divide` does nothing:  `as` assembles `mov $(15/2), %eax` just fine with or without `--divide`.

So you should be fine to take it out.  If it's a problem and clang does treat `/` as a comment character on some platforms, it should usually result in build-time failure, not binaries with hidden bugs.

---

And yes, `-divide` apparently does the same thing as `--divide`.  But you might want to try `--divide` in case clang's assembler only supports the more-standard double-`-` form.